# Blender Solidify Modifier Adding Thickness Seperately (Seperate Angles For Different Faces)

Tags: solidify-modifier

I applied a solify modifier, but the shape seems to split into 2 directions. May I know how to solve this?

Currently it looks like this:
[image]

I want it to look like this:
[image]

Can anyone help?

Comment: This looks like split edges on the loop where the division in the shell appears. Select all in Edit Mode,  M > Merge > By Distance. See if that works.

Comment: @RobinBetts hi yes, this has solved the problem. thank you very much! is there any reason this happens? as the first time I did it, it worked alright, the second time had a split.

Comment: I can't tell, of course, but a very common cause is imagining that a right-click on an extrusion cancels the extrusion. It doesn't. It cancels the _move_, leaving a 0-length extrusion (invisibly) in place. Ctrl-Z is needed to get rid of the recently-created faces.